# python nosetests give wrong result

Tags: python, testing

I have strange situation. I have code as (from Z.Shaw Learn the python the hard way):

```
WORD_TYPES={
   'verb' : ['go', 'kill', 'eat'],
   'direction' : ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
   'noun' : ['bear', 'princess'],
   'stop' : ['the','in','of'],
   'adjective': ['beautiful','cool','nice']
   }

VOCABULARY={word: word_type for word_type, words in WORD_TYPES.items() for word in words}

def scan(sentence):
    tokens=[]
    for word in sentence.lower().split():
        try:
            word_type=VOCABULARY[word]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                value=int(word)
            except ValueError:
                tokens.append(('error',word))
            else:
                tokens.append(('int',word))

    else:
        tokens.append((word_type,word))

    for i in range(0,len(tokens)):
         if tokens[i][0] == "error":
            del tokens[i]
return tokens
```

When I tries it with word "Beautiful" - it returns as expected

```
[('adjective', u'beautiful')]
```

But nosetests give unpredictable result and I cant see the reason:

```
from nose.tools import *
from Ex_48 import lexicon
def test_upper_lower_letters():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("Beautiful"),[('adjective','beautiful')])
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("BEauTiful"),[('adjective','beautiful')])
```

This is what I get:

```
C:\Python27\projects\skeleton\tests>nosetests tests_Ex_48
.......F
======================================================================
FAIL: tests_Ex_48.test_upper_lower_letters
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python27\projects\skeleton\tests\tests_Ex_48.py", line 58, in test_upper_lower_letters
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("Beautiful"),[('adjective','beautiful')])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('error', 'Beautiful')] != [('adjective', 'beautiful')]

First differing element 0:
('error', 'Beautiful')
('adjective', 'beautiful')

- [('error', 'Beautiful')]
+ [('adjective', 'beautiful')]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Please help

Comment: The second else is not correctly indented, I'm guessing this is a copy-paste error? Two additional remarks. Why add the 'error' tokens and then remove them later on? Second, the loop that removes 'error' tokens is altering the list while iterating, which is a disaster waiting to happen. Change that to tokens = [token for token in tokens if token[0] != 'error'].

Comment: Yeap, this is copy-paste error

Comment: I think the second remark is breaking stuff, try to fix that, see if it helps (I mean the list alteration while iterating stuff).

Comment: No, It didnt help. The same result. Code works as expected but nosetests return the error((